# How can I sort using more than one criteria with a UsedRange?

Tags: excel, vba

I am wracking my brain trying to get this one sorted out. What I am trying to accomplish is to sort a number of rows in a spreadsheet based upon criteria of a cell in that row.

So, out of 200 rows, for example, I want to sort 50 of them by columns S & P. Then, for maybe 20 other rows, I want to sort them by column N. The number of rows is dependent upon using a row count. I verified the row count was working with the MsgBox lastRow command.

All of my other code works fine - I sort, delete UsedRange.Rows, etc (VMC:).

In SortThree: is the failure.

I turn filter mode off, it sorts the sheet using my criteria, lastRow is the correct number, and then when I try to apply the actual filter to sort it by Column S (19) and then Column P (16), it does nothing.

```
VMC:
        If Sheets(2).FilterMode Then Sheets(2).AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:="0-VMC"
        If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row.Count = 0 Then GoTo SortThree
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete

SortThree:
If Sheets(2).FilterMode Then Sheets(2).AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:="3*"
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox lastRow
        .Range("A2:AA" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 19), Order:=xlAscending, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Key2:=.Cells(2, 16), Order:=xlAscending, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
                  .Apply
.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: not sure if this is your problem our not, but your lastRow reference is not appropriately qualified.  Depending on the complexity of your code, this will cause you all kinds of headaches once you stop debugging and run the code end-to-end.

Comment: When I apply that filter, the last row is 104. The lastRow that pops up via "MsgBox lastRow", shows a value of 104. So to me, that means that part is working properly.

Comment: it's only working because you have the sheet selected.  Select another sheet and run the code.  Unless you're selecting the sheet somewhere else in the code, your lastRow is returning the value of the currently selected sheet, not necessarily Sheets(2).

Comment: I was very cautious that only the current sheet was working, whether it be Sheets(2) or ActiveSheet. I walk through the code - it's working until the .Range part of "SortThree:".

Answer (score 0):

The order argument for a VBA [Range.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) is Order1, Order2 and (if necessary) Order3. These coincide with Key1, Key2 and Key3. You do not require .Apply. SortOn:=xlSortOnValues is not a valid argument; it belongs to Sort.SortFields.Add which is another type of Sort altogether. You cannot mix-and-match the two Sort methods.

```
...
.Range("A2:AA" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 19), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                               Key2:=.Cells(2, 16), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                               Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
...
```